# iOS: How do I use Google Maps to get directions based on user input?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiwebview, geolocation

I am building an application that must take user's input of a start location, and two destinations and show the route between the three. I have used google maps api in my project to add a map view, but the google directions API is not meant for user input. Should I use the google maps javascript API or add a web view. How would I go about using either?

Google Maps Javascript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Directions

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905797/google-maps-ios-sdk-getting-directions-between-2-locations

Answer (score 1):

What about the option of having the user launch either google maps or maps with the direction? To do that there's a pretty good answer here: [How to Open Google Map Navigation Url with Direction and Voice in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469570/how-to-open-google-map-navigation-url-with-direction-and-voice-in-ios)

Multitasking on the phone is pretty good these days so it shouldn't cause too much user annoyance to have another app (built to directions) take over that job. The only reason I'd see to not do it that way is if your app is something like Uber, but if that's the case then there's a few other things you could do.

Comment: I want to handle it in the app itself. But with your solution, can I add multiple destinations?